# how to use colormap on javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, javascript-import

I need to have a colormap on my javascript page.
I am using Flask for server side (written in python).
I have a javascript file that requires colormap module (installed using "npm install colormap"), for rendering colormaps on the client side.
I tried to import it from my javascript file index.js

```
var colormap = import("colormap");
```

which I got the error:

```
index.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier 'colormap'
    at index.js:2
```

and I also tried:

```
let colormap = require('colormap')
```

and I got the error require is not defined.

how can I solve it?
I am trying to import the js file with colormap directly into my html (so the javascript file will have reference), but I cant find what file should I import.

Comment: I want to try and add the <script> tag, but I dont understand which file should I add (installing the module added multiple files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPM package `colormap` is not set up well for just importing into a client-side JS script.

If it was, you could just include it in a script tag as described [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/unpkg-an-open-source-cdn-for-npm).

Because it is not, you will have to use [Browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage) to convert the JS into a file that you can then serve and use in your JS.